# How to get the Sharepoint Document library fields into GridView

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0, sharepoint-2010

I have grid-view in Windows Application. Now i want to display the shared document field values into grid-view. Can anybody have solutions????

```
        IEnumerable<Sp.ListItem> list;
        Sp.ClientContext spcontext = new ClientContext("http://Sharepointsite");
        Sp.Web spsite = spcontext.Web;
        Sp.ListCollection lcollection = spsite.Lists;
        var productlist = spcontext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Shared Documents/Photo");
        Sp.CamlQuery cm = new CamlQuery();
        IQueryable<Sp.ListItem> mylist = productlist.GetItems(cm);
        list = spcontext.LoadQuery(mylist);
        spcontext.ExecuteQuery();
        var qry = (from prd in list
                   select new
                   {

                       Name = prd.FieldValues.Values.ElementAt(1).ToString(),
                       Custom = prd.FieldValues.Values.ElementAt(2).ToString(),

                   }).ToList();

        dataGridView1.DataSource = qry;
```

Error: List 'Shared Documents/Photo' does not exist at site with URL in Sharepointsite

Comment: add sample code and where you are stuck with so that anybody can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `Photo` is a Folder in your Document Library you can't take it like a List Title.

if you change your empty Caml Query to

```
var productlist = spcontext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Shared Documents");

var folderName = "Photo";


Sp.CamlQuery cm = new Sp.CamlQuery();
cm.ViewXml = "<View Scope=\"RecursiveAll\"> " +
"<Query>" +
   "<Where>" +
   "<And>" +
     "<Eq>" +
       "<FieldRef Name=\"FSObjType\" />" +
       "<Value Type=\"Integer\">1</Value>" +
     "</Eq>" +
     "<Eq>" +
       "<FieldRef Name=\"Title\"/>" +
       "<Value Type=\"Text\">" + folderName + "</Value>" +
     "</Eq>" +
   "</And>" +
   "</Where>" +
 "</Query>" +
 "</View>";
```

It will fetch all Folder in the Document Library which have that Name.

Now if you want a List of the FieldValue you can change your LinQ Query to something like this:

```
 var qry = (from prd in list.ElementAt(0).FieldValues
           select new 
           {
               Key = prd.Key,
               Value = prd.Value
           }).ToList();
```

And now you have a collection with all Field Names and their Values. Which can be sorted/filtered what ever.

**Edit:**

If you want to select only some Fields of the collection one opportunity is to add a where clause to your linq query:

```
var qry = (from prd in list.ElementAt(0).FieldValues
           where prd.Key == "Title"
           select new 
           {
               Key = prd.Key,
               Value = prd.Value
           }).ToList();
```

Comment: i have one doubt. How to select particular field in Photo folder??

Answer (score -1):

Error itself suggesting that problem with this line
 var productlist = spcontext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Shared Documents/Photo");